# Does anyone know the way to undelete file on ZFS?

Tags: data-recovery, zfs, deleted-files, copy-on-write

Is there any way to undelete file on ZFS.
I overwrote JPG file with the scanned image.
Unfortunately, I didn't take snapshot.
But ZFS uses the CoW mechanism, overwritten data may still alive, I think.
Does anyone know the way to undelete file on ZFS?

Comment: Stop using the disk. Try a tool like `photorec`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I followed your advice nad tried `photorec`. As a result, I recovered some JPG files. However, my target file was not there. Strangely, `photorec` couldn't recover well almost JPG files which is not deleted. And I remembered that unfortunately my pool had a setting for lz4 compression.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how well data recovery tools can work when the data on the disk is compressed. AFAIK the CoW mechanism is only meant to prevent data loss during the process of overwriting a file. When the file is closed, the directory structure will be switched to point to the new data instead of the old data. The area where the old data was stored can then be overwritten by other write operations.

Answer (score 0):

UFS Explorer RAID Recovery declares recovery from ZFS but I did not use it myself:

https://www.ufsexplorer.com/ufs-explorer-raid-recovery.php